# In Ecto, using a query function in a query with a join

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have 2 models `Player` and `Event`. A player has_many events. I have an ecto query that gets the top scorers as follows:

```
from(p in Player,
  join: s in assoc(p, :events),
  group_by: [p.id],
  select: %{total_goals: count(s.id), player: p},
  where: s.type == "goal_scored",
  where: p.team_id == ^team_id,
  order_by: [desc: count(s.id)],
  limit: 10
)
|> Repo.all()
```

This works fine, but in my `Event` model I have a handy function to only query events of type `goal_scored`:

```
def goals(query) do
  from(e in query, where: e.type == "goal_scored")
end
```

Is there any way I can use this query function in my query containing the join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Ecto.Query.dynamic/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#dynamic/2) is your friend here. It’s impossible directly with the full query in `Event`, but you might split it that way:

```rb
def goal_scored_condition do
  dynamic([e], e.type == "goal_scored")
end

def goals(query) do
  conditions = goal_scored_condition()
  from(e in query, where: ^conditions)
end
```

and in `Player`

```rb
conditions = Event.goal_scored_condition()
from(p in Player,
  ...
  where: ^conditions,
  ...
```

---

In some cases, [`Ecto.Query.subquery/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html?#subquery/2) might be helpful as well.

Comment: nice, that looks like the best solution